# How to read from cin into a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to build a mine sweeper like program that reads in program from stdin.
The input is in the form

```
4 4
..*.
*...
....
**..
```

I have defined `vector<vector<char>> mine_field` and have resized it to the dimensions of the field. I envisioned reading in the input a line at a time like this (of course this would only be the first line)

```
 cin >> mine_field[0];
```

However, this does not work. What would be the best way to do this?

**Edit:** I also thought about looping and storing the value in each index, but wouldn't this try to put the whole `string` in each index where there is room only for a `char`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you need to resize your vector to the limits (rowSize, colSize).

```
vector<vector<char> > mine_field (rowSize, vector<char> (colSize));
```

Analogously, you can initialize all positions using this same declarations.

```
vector<vector<char> > mine_field (rowSize, vector<char> (colSize, 'a'));
```

All positions in the mine_field vector will be initialize with the char `a`.

To read from `cin`, just read normally:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < colSize; j++){
        cin >> mine_field[i][j];
    }
}`
```

Comment: Thank you. I have mine_field declared in a class, is it possible to initialize it to a size in the constructor? I currently have `mine_fields.resize(columns, vector<char>(rows));`

Comment: Yes, it's possible, just declare the variable and initialize it. See:
http://pastebin.com/m3ncm7NG

Comment: No, more like `class field {vector< vector<char> > mine_field;}` I have to read in the first two lines of the input before I can initialize it to a size, but I won't know that yet in the class declaration

Answer (score 1):

You need to `cin >> vector<char>`firstly according to your define. Then `vector <vector<char> >`, following for your reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector <vector<char> > mine_field;
    int row, col;
    char c;
    vector<char> line;
    for (row=0; row<4; ++row)
    {
        line.clear();
        for (col=0; col<4; ++col)
        {
           cin >> c;
           line.push_back(c);
        }
        mine_field.push_back(line);
    }
    vector<vector<char> >::iterator it = mine_field.begin();
    cout << "print result: " << endl;
    for(;it!=mine_field.end(); ++it)
    {
        vector<char>::iterator itIn = it->begin();
        for(; itIn!=it->end(); ++itIn)
            cout <<*itIn;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, and I thought of doing this, but I'd rather not have to dynamically resize my vector when I know the exact size before hand